# Alternative to `numpy.tile` for periodic mask

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image, stored in a numpy array of `uint8`s, of shape `(planes, rows, cols)`. I need to compare it to the values stored in a mask, also of `uint8`s, of shape `(mask_rows, mask_cols)`. While the image may be very large, the mask is usually smallish, normally `(256, 256)` and is to be tiled over `image`. To simplify the code, lets pretend that `rows = 100 * mask_rows` and `cols = 100 * mask_cols`.

The way I am currently handling this thresholding is something like this:

```
out = image >= np.tile(mask, (image.shape[0], 100, 100))
```

The largest array I can process this way before getting slapped in the face with a `MemoryError` is a little larger than `(3, 11100, 11100)`. The way I figured it, doing things this way I have up to three ginormous arrays coexisting in memory: `image`, the tiled `mask`, and my return `out`. But the tiled mask is the same little array copied over and over 10,000 times. So if I could spare that memory, I would use only 2/3 the memory, and should be able to process images 3/2 larger, so of size around `(3, 13600, 13600)`. This is, by the way, consistent with what I get if I do the thresholding in place with

```
np.greater_equal(image, (image.shape[0], 100, 100), out=image)
```

My (failed) attempt at exploiting the periodic nature of `mask` to process larger arrays has been to index `mask` with periodic linear arrays:

```
mask = mask[None, ...]
rows = np.tile(np.arange(mask.shape[1], (100,))).reshape(1, -1, 1)
cols = np.tile(np.arange(mask.shape[2], (100,))).reshape(1, 1, -1)
out = image >= mask[:, rows, cols]
```

For small arrays it does produce the same result as the other one, although with something of a 20x slowdown(!!!), but it terribly fails to perform for the larger sizes. Instead of a `MemoryError` it eventually crashes python, even for values that the other method handles with no problems.

What I think is happening is that numpy is actually constructing the `(planes, rows, cols)` array to index `mask`, so not only is there no memory saving, but since it is an array of `int32`s, it is actually taking four times more space to store...

Any ideas on how to go about this? To spare you the trouble, find below some sandbox code to play around with:

```
import numpy as np

def halftone_1(image, mask) :
    return np.greater_equal(image, np.tile(mask, (image.shape[0], 100, 100)))

def halftone_2(image, mask) :
    mask = mask[None, ...]
    rows = np.tile(np.arange(mask.shape[1]),
                   (100,)).reshape(1, -1, 1)
    cols = np.tile(np.arange(mask.shape[2]),
                   (100,)).reshape(1, 1, -1)
    return np.greater_equal(image, mask[:, rows, cols])

rows, cols, planes = 6000, 6000, 3
image = np.random.randint(-2**31, 2**31 - 1, size=(planes * rows * cols // 4))
image = image.view(dtype='uint8').reshape(planes, rows, cols)
mask = np.random.randint(256,
                         size=(1, rows // 100, cols // 100)).astype('uint8')

#np.all(halftone_1(image, mask) == halftone_2(image, mask))
#halftone_1(image, mask)
#halftone_2(image, mask)

import timeit
print timeit.timeit('halftone_1(image, mask)',
                    'from __main__ import halftone_1, image, mask',
                    number=1)
print timeit.timeit('halftone_2(image, mask)',
                    'from __main__ import halftone_2, image, mask',
                    number=1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would almost have pointed you to a [rolling window](https://gist.github.com/3866040) type of trick, but for this simple non-overlapping thing, normal reshape does it just as well. (the reshapes here are safe, numpy will *never* make a copy for them)

```
def halftone_reshape(image, mask):
    # you can make up a nicer reshape code maybe, it is a bit ugly. The
    # rolling window code can do this too (but much more general then reshape).
    new_shape = np.array(zip(image.shape, mask.shape))
    new_shape[:,0] /= new_shape[:,1]
    reshaped_image = image.reshape(new_shape.ravel())

    reshaped_mask = mask[None,:,None,:,None,:]

    # and now they just broadcast:
    result_funny_shaped = reshaped_image >= reshaped_mask

    # And you can just reshape it back:
    return result_funny_shaped.reshape(image.shape)
```

And since timings are everything (not really but...):

```
In [172]: %timeit halftone_reshape(image, mask)
1 loops, best of 3: 280 ms per loop

In [173]: %timeit halftone_1(image, mask)
1 loops, best of 3: 354 ms per loop

In [174]: %timeit halftone_2(image, mask)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.1 s per loop
```

Comment: Beautiful! I was banging my head on a solution similar to this, but was having trouble getting the order of the extra dimensions right. If I could, I would give you an extra +1 for the link to the rolling window trick. And just to confirm: this does require that the mask divide the image exactly, if it doesn't, I am guessing that padding the image until it does is the way to go, and that it can be done in place with `image.resize`, right?

Comment: @Jaime, true, but if you need to pad, you need to copy (it *may* be possible to copy inside the same data segment, but really lets keep realistic...). The only thing to avoid that would be using some `scipy.ndimage` tool, or handle the boundaries yourself explicitly. And the ndimage things will probably all overlap the mask.

Comment: @Jaime OK, nvm... it seems resize actually does manage to do that memory moving around (if you are lucky)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am going to experiment a little bit with this to see where it takes me, and if I can't figure it out myself will come back with a new question.

Comment: This is ridiculously effective! If I do the `>=` in place, it can threshold any array that fits into memory!